# How to fill detail view in SplitView with mapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, uisplitviewcontroller, detailview

I'm trying to learn some basic iOS development, but for some reason when I try to add a mapView to the detailView in my splitView (lots of views, I know..) app, the map doesn't feel the entire view.

Any ideas why?

Pic proof:

[image]

Note, I've only built this on the storyboard so far, so mayhap I'm missing something programmatic of which I'm currently ignorant?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you added layout constraints on the map? If not you should add leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints for the map to its container. It will then grow/shrink when the layout changes.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel thanks for the tip, but oddly those options are greyed out. Not sure why that is the case, though.

Comment: Odd. You should be able to select the mapkit view and then add constraints using the constraint tool.